# Symfony 2.8 : dynamic containers parameters at compiler pass and used in security.yml

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, compiler-construction, containers

I'm facing an issue I can't solve by myself in my Symfony 2.8 API project:

I have some paramter loaded at compiler pass in the DependencyInjection of one of my bundle:

```
class ParametersCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        //loads api version from database when container gets built.
        $api_version = $container->get('doctrine')->getRepository('MyAppEntityBundle:Parameter')
            ->findOneBy(['name' => 'api_version']);
        if (!$api_version) {
            throw new MyAppException('api_version couldnt be found in database during container build process.');
        }
        $container->setParameter('api_version', $api_version);
    }
}
```

I dont want this parameter in paramters_*.yml files, to ensure it's ALWAYS retrieved from db + I use it in security.yml file, such as:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api/%api_version%/
```

How can I achieved that ?

Apparently, $container->setParameter('name', $value); doesnt work if there isnt a parameter in parameter_*.yml file with dummy value in parameters.yml
+ I need to set these values BEFORE security.yml gets parsed and loaded.
I have look into symfony core for hours, spotted where security config is loaded from kernel->boot() process but I dont see how to achieve what I want properly.

Any help or hints on the proper method would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: All of the config file parsing is done before any of the passes are called.  So yes you will always need a dummy value.  Nothing to do with setParameter.  You can take a look at how the SecurityBundle passes makes it's services and possible change the definition in your pass.  But accessing the database from inside a pass is unusual.  I'm skeptical that it will even work.

Comment: What is the goal of the firewall? As stated, using the compiler pass will act as a cache of the db value at compile time `app/console cache:warmup` and won't change when the db value does, unless you recompile your app. This would be confusing and undesirable in production. It makes more sense to utilize a [security provider](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/api_key_authentication.html#only-authenticating-for-certain-urls) to validate the user at access time rather than at compile time. You can then execute your own query to validate the `api_version` for each request.

Comment: @Cerad, I deleted this from my source code but i'm pretty sure it was, maybe because by luck, doctrine was built in container just before the pass of my bundle ? Or every vendor's bundle is built before mine ? Sorry these are asumptions.
Ok I see what to do with changing the Security service definition but it is overkill in complexity for what I want to achieve, thanks for the tip anyway !

Comment: @fyrye Its not about making a firewall ( = checking authorization like you say with a security provider, which I have with proper JWT system), I'm searching for a way to automatize API deployement by setting from an admin app the new version of the api to deploy in DB (to be short, it's a bit more complicated than that, + mobile apps update needs) and THEN deploy it. Thanks for the tip but I think checking api_version each request is not good for perfs :)

Comment: @yfhrpcx The firewall's purpose is to determine "when authentication occurs". I would contend that it would depend on your desired result. Since authentication should occur for all `^/api` requests. Routing of the versions would then be handled by the API controller(s) `/api/{version}`. Your current approach would disable authentication when the `api_version` is changed. e.g. a request for `/api/v1` is made when `api_version: 'v2'` is that your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly not a good practice, as I stated in response to previous comments, I admit it, it is overkill in complexity for a simple API version management issue. I end up setting the parameter in parameters.yml file so when security.yml file is processed, it is not a problem, and placed my API management logic in the build process of the CI. Makes more sense. 
@Mocrates Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be work but i dont know if is a good practice ... a SecurityExtension create a dynamic service for each firewalls request matcher and the id is encrypted by an md5 and a sha1 ... you can override arguments.

see a method createRequestMatcher in Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension

Comment: * moved to answer to close question *

Comment: i agree and for me a best solution is in config file too